# Can I have minslides, maxslides and have the thumbnail pager as well?

Tags: bxslider

U would be grateful if someone knew a solution to my problem. What I am looking for is to have multiple slides on screen, but also a thumbnail pager under it.

[image]

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/3w35U/2/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/fashion" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 .bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
     bottom: -95px;
 }
 .bx-wrapper .bx-pager img {
     width:40px;
     height:40px;
 }
 .bx-wrapper .bx-pager a {
     border: solid #ccc 1px;
     display: block;
     margin: 0 5px;
     padding: 3px;
 }
 .bx-wrapper .bx-pager a:hover, .bx-wrapper .bx-pager a.active {
     border: solid #5280DD 3px;
 }
 .bx-wrapper {
     margin-bottom: 120px;
 }
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 200,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 3,
    moveSlides: 1,
    buildPager: function (slideIndex) {
        switch (slideIndex) {
            case 0:
                return '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city">';
            case 1:
                return '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/fashion">';
            case 2:
                return '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals">';
            case 3:
                return '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food">';
            case 4:
                return '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports">';
        }
    }

});
```

EDIT: In the fiddle the images in the slider may/may not match the images in the pager. This is not a code issue but because the images are fetched randomly from an external server called LoremIpsum which generated random images for different tags like food, fashon, sports.